# How much number of the access will need memcached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

Currently, I'm thinking of creating the web site, in which there will be about 10,000UVs and 500,000PVs daily.

I'm using Rails3.2.11 with many gems.
There will be many images uploading.
Do you guys think I'll need to use memcached for fast performance?
Or not needed for this amount?

I took a look at how to use `Dalli` and `Memcached` on Railscasts but it looked that I have to re-code a lots part in my app.

If it takes too much time, and memcache is not needed for the amount of accesses I wish, I won't use it.
I'll just go without memcached.

What do you think?

P.S. If anyone knows how to speed up the performance easily, plase tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's a valid reason to expect that much visitors on day one, you're usually best starting small and then scale as the load ramps up on your app server (caching and adding more servers)

So, for a start, don't bother with memcached ... if your service is a success, then it'll be worth the trouble to include caching